# Prononciations du toponyme « Montréal » en français du Québec ?

Tags: prononciation, québec, toponymes, accents-régionaux

« Montréal est prononcé [mɔ̃ʁeal] <sup>[écouter](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Fr-Montr%C3%A9al.ogg)</sup> en français standard, [mɒ̃ʁeal] <sup>[écouter](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Qc-Montr%C3%A9al.ogg) <sup>Note 2</sup></sup> en [français québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) et [ˌmʌntriːˈɒl] <sup>[écouter](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Montreal-English-pronunciation.oga)</sup> en anglais canadien » nous dit l'[article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montr%C3%A9al#Toponymie) Wikipédia au sujet du [toponyme](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/ToposWeb/Fiche.aspx?no_seq=42164) (voir aussi [gentilé](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1836)) de cette ville du Québec (Canada). La note (2) ajoute :

> La prononciation peut varier selon les locuteurs. Par exemple, le /r/
>   peut être prononcé de plusieurs façons [r], [ʁ], [ʀ] selon la
>   génération, de même que le /ɔ̃/ peut également se prononcer [ɔ̃] ou
>   [õ]. [ [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montr%C3%A9al#Toponymie) ]

Je peux prononcer de différentes manières, dont celle du locuteur du Québec dans l'audio, mais j'ai l'impression de dire surtout [mɒ̃ʀjal] et, de manière plus « rapide » ou relâchée, [mɔʀjal] ; j'ai de la difficulté à faire l'adéquation entre ce que j'entends de ce que je dis et l'API. La note ne parle pas de ce genre de transformation du dernier son...

---

1. Peut-on confirmer que [mɒ̃ʁeal] soit la manière la plus usuelle au Québec de prononcer le toponyme « Montréal » ?
2. A-t-on des précisions sur quelle génération prononce de telle ou
   telle manière quoi ou sur d'autres types de [différences](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Variations_r.C3.A9gionales_2) ?
3. En quoi consiste la « transformation » dont fait état ma [prononciation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) ([mɒ̃ʀjal], [mɔʀjal])
   et que révèle-t-elle le cas échéant, ou n'était-ce qu'une impression ?
4. Existe-t-il une prononciation davantage fréquente chez les
   francophones de Montréal indépendamment de tout autre facteur ?

Comment: La majorité des gens au Québec le prononce différemment. Selon leur accent. Il n'y a pas de façon parfaite de le dire. Une chose certaine est que personne ne prononce le t.

Comment: @milk2go Vous, vous le dites comment ? Je n'ai jamais porté attention aux différentes manières de la prononcer, autrement que dans un contexte de dérision avec un truc comme :  _je veux voir l'écrapou et les accidents de machine du Journal de mourial_. Merci.

Answer (score 4):

La manière la plus commune au Québec pour dire Montréal est bien [mɒ̃ʁeal]. Comme spécifié dans l'article Wikipedia, il y a différentes façons de prononcer ce nom selon l'interlocuteur.

On utilise généralement [mɒ̃ʁeal].

La majorité des immigrants ou des Montréalais qui parlent anglais prononcent [ˌmʌntriːˈɒl].

Certaines personnes pour diverses raisons (accent étranger, manque d'éducation, déformation du langage, etc.) prononcent à tort [mɔ̃ʁejal] ou [mɒ̃ʀjal]. Vous m'excuserez si la forme n'est pas bonne, mais textuellement [mɔ̃ʁejal] se prononcerait : Monréyal.

Source : je suis moi-même québécois. J'ai été amené à interagir avec la majorité des interlocuteurs typiques qu'on retrouve au Québec.

Comment: Est-ce qu'«à tord» est une torsion volontaire à la norme pour exprimer plus que la somme des mots de la phrase, ou une fabuleuse coquille qui tombe pile poile pour une généreuse poilade?

Answer (score -1):

Le « on » se prononce [ɒ̃], parce qu'il est avant le « r ».